# Maven JAR module depends on classes in WAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, war

I have an application which is packaged as a .war file. It has GWT code and a set of web-services.

I want to move the web-services code to a separate jar file, so the application can be build without them.

**Services depend on code which is currently packaged into .war file, so in pom.xml for jar file I specify the following dependency:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-war</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**But to package the .war archive I also need to specify a dependency for the jar, like this:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-services-jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Which results in Circular Dependency.**

How do I solve this? Or maybe I should follow a different approach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modularize a little more - introduce say a core jar with the dependencies common between my-war and my-services-jar and then your dependency structure will not have the circular dependency.

```
my-war
    - core-jar
my-services-jar
    - core-jar
```

Comment: Nice way, but I'd like to avoid it, because of tightly coupled code in the war file. I will, however, follow this if there's no other way

Comment: This is the right way. If you really can't, because of legacy, try to filter with maven-dependency-plugin ... but this is really a bad solution. +1 for Biju's answer